# toggling a sidebar in React

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I created a simple app to work through an issue I'm having toggling a sidebar. I'm trying to use onClicks so that I can open and close a sidebar, and yet can't get it to work. I'm using styled-components, and for whatever reason I can't get the sidebar to toggle. I have a simple piece of state, isOpen, which is initialized to false, and when i click on a button in the 'navbar', i'd like it to toggle state to true via an onClick, and the sidebar should appear, and yet, it isn't working.

Here is the codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/toggling-sidebar-nyoqn?file=/src/Navbar.js)

I tried re-writing the app from scratch, using destructuring vs not using destructuring, and looked for any bugs in the code but couldn't. Any ideas for what I can try next? Also I made sure to use arrow functions for my onClicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue I see is that the `SidebarContainer` is creating an overlay that prevents clicking on the button to open it. You'll need to change the `visibility` property on the `SidebarContainer` that's exported from `SidebarElements`:

`visibility: ${(props) => (props.isOpen ? "visible" : "hidden")};`

I prefer using the `visibility` property over setting `display` to `block` or `none` because if you want to you can animate or transition properties like `opacity` or `transform`. When toggling the `display` property your sidebar will just appear and disappear instantly.

Something else, you don't need to use an anonymous callback when calling the `toggle` from inside of `Sidebar` and `Navbar`:

`<CloseIcon onClick={toggle}>X</CloseIcon>`

`<OpenIcon onClick={toggle}>open sidebar</OpenIcon>`

I've updated the [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/toggling-sidebar-forked-r2phx?file=/src/Navbar.js) you provided.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code

1. You are calling the toggle like `onClick={() => toggle}` when you should be calling it like `onClick={toggle}` or `onClick={() => toggle()}`
2. Your "sidebar" is a overlapping your navbar (*it is `position:fixed` with `opacity:0` and covers the whole screen*)

So fix 1 and then either move the sidebar elsewhere (as to not overlap) or change its `display` from `none` to `block` instead of the opacity.